# Choosing the best fitting model with AIC and p-value

Tags: p-value, model-selection, aic, garch

I have a financial time series, exchange rates.
Between ARCH(10) and GARCH(1,1) I would like to see which model fits best my TS. For ARCH I have a *p-value* smaller than 0.05 and for GARCH *p-value* is bigger than 0.05. I know what to do with the null hypothesis but my question is: for ARCH I have a smaller AIC value. Shoul I choose the ARCH model, despite the fact that I reject my null hypothesis?

Comment: Your question fits in a not-so-small group of questions of model selection based on AIC vs. p-value. I do not think it is conceptually different from these questions and therefore is a duplicate of one or more of them. Consider reviewing these questions first. See e.g. the answers in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262138/which-model-should-be-chosen-using-aicc-bic-and-p-value).

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: So has your question been answered, or are you still looking for an answer? If you found a duplicate, could you link it here?